# Provisioning profile for ios app

Tags: iphone, ios

I have uploaded an app before and for that I made a provisioning profile now I wonder if I could use that for my new app or do I have to create a new provisioning profile for that.

Comment: No problem with provisioning profiles,only the app bundle identifier should unique..

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to. You can use the same provisioning profile for installing multiple apps.